# Drupal Export of Site Not Working For Subdirectory Levels Beyond Root Directory

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have to move an existing Drupal site from one server to another. I've done so by doing a mysql database export/import and copying over the files to the new server. On the new system, the root page comes up fine but if I try to go to any deeper directory levels I get a 404 Not Found Error.

so  drupal.newserver.com -> works fine
but drupal.newserver.com/user -> gives me a 404 and happens,same for all subdirectories

Is there something that I'm missing that is part of a drupal export? Could it be related to the structure of the /sites directory which is under the webserver's docroot?- which has a folder named after the old server (ie drupal.oldserver.com but not drupal.newserver.com? Also, I noticed that there are _htaccess files and .hta files but not .htaccess files in the site files that I've copied over.

Sorry if I'm asking a bleedingly obvious question - I'm very new to Drupal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let anyone who might come across via a google search - I was able to get this to work . It turns out that while mod_rewrite was enabled, what I had to do was to enable the AllowOverride directive for the web directory in httpd.conf to be set to ‘All’. If it’s not set to this, the server won’t respect the .htaccess rules you put into the drupal directory. It’s been a while since I’ve worked with apache config files so it took a while to finally piece it together. The main breakthrough came when I realized that if I turned off clean-urls then the links worked but looked ugly and then was able to research clean_url.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the clean url is enabled in your web server. To check try this:

```
drupal.newserver.com/?q=user.
```

Comment: hmm, doing <url>/?q=user results in a "Not Found" page that looks like a response straight from the server. Reading something else along those lines, <url>?q=admin/settings/clean-urls gives me an access denied message. This page however has the branding and styling of the rest of the pages in this site.

Comment: did u modify the settings.php file with the new database name and password?

Comment: sorry if I'm being unclear /?q=user seems to redirect to <url>/user and then it gives me a Not Found error message. I have updated the settings.php file in the default folder to reflect the new db information as well.

Comment: You mean to say that after giving user id and password in the login page it takes you to Not Found error message?

Comment: No - it doesn't even give me the option of entering a username and password - putting in the <url>/?q=user url redirects to <url>/user where I then see "Not Found - the requested URL /user was not found on this server." Thanks for your help!

Comment: just taking a look at the webserver's errors logs, I'm seeing this error:  [Mon May 13 16:04:05 2013] [error] [client xxxxx] File does not exist: /var/www/html/user  so it doesn't appear that the system is correctly mapping the /user request into Drupal's url control system

Comment: check with the hosting provider

Comment: what should I check with the provider? I'm working with my company's sys admin, not a hosting provider so hopefully I have more flexible options but I'm not quite sure where to go with this.